# How would one determine which apple push notification server (APNS) is in use, from iOS application

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, server-push

I wish to include in my registration message to our server, a flag as to which APNS server is being used. sandbox or production. I wish to do this so that my code can simply look up the device token and notification server from the table of devices, so that continuing development can coexist with live devices.

The application does, in development, register properly, linking a customer ID in our system to the token string from the phone.

However, this does not allow me to determine programatically from our server which push notification server to use.

Comment: Well, guess that you are taking the registration token and send it to your server through a NSURLRequest. Simply add another paramater to the url that specifies if the app is in development of in production. Your server will then know what to do. I hope I understood the problem ok.

Comment: After reading a lot and looking at @George's comment (which I think I agree with) it seems that you want **your** App's code (in the device) to tell **your** server whether to use **Apple's** APNS sandbox or production server.  In which case I'd do what George suggests (and ignore my answer - although what I answered does give you feedback that what you got is what you asked for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I have your question right, but as per Apple's doc [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide: The Notification Payload](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1)

> Providers can specify custom payload values outside the Apple-reserved
>   aps namespace.

So all you need to do is craft your custom payload to indicate which server the notification was pushed from, and read it when it gets to the App.